# How To Detect A Empty Column python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I Use Openpyxl Module

What I try to make:

[image: What I Try To Make]

Please tell how to make it and explain the detail.

I already try to make it but its just a forever loop :

```
sdp = mywbname[mysheetname]
perk = True
rows = "G"
column = 5
cell = rows+str(column)

print(cell)


while (perk == True):
    print(sdp[cell].value)
    column+=1
    if sdp[cell].value == "None":
        perk = False
    else:
        perk = True
```

Comment: You probably need the condition to be `if sdp[column] is None`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `worksheet.calculate_dimension()` method which gives you the minimum bounding box of not-empty data as a range.

Then you can use one of the attributes of the range like `cell_range.min_row` or `cell_range.bottom` depending on exactly what you are looking for

Documentation about worksheet:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=worksheet

Documentation about cell_range:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=worksheet